# Is it possible to scrape html data- attributes with XPath selectors (lxml)?

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to scrape all of the careers pages from this website: http://wearemadeinny.com/find-a-job/

I tried the below, but unfortunately the hrefs only appear when you click into one of the company pages:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get("http://wearemadeinny.com/find-a-job/")
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.text)

jobs = tree.xpath('//*[@id="venue-hiring"]/a/@href')

links = [x for x in jobs]

print links
```

I noticed that each `<li>` contains html data attributes which contain the job page urls.  So, is it possible to scrape the data-hiringurl attribute from each `<li>`. If not with lxml and XPath selectors are their other options?

This is one of the `<li>` elements that I would like to pull from. I would specifically like to pull the data-hiringurl="http://www.admeld.com/about/jobs/"  The xpath to this element is //*[@id="v7"]

```
<li id="v7" data-vid="7" data-name="Admeld" data-address="230 Park Avenue South Suite 1201" data-lat="40.7378349" data-long="-73.9886703" data-url="http://www.admeld.com/" data-hiring="1" data-hiringurl="http://www.admeld.com/about/jobs/" data-whynyc="" data-category="1"><a href="#" class="list-digital">
<span class="venue-name">Admeld</span><br>
<span class="venue-address">230 Park Avenue South</span>
<br><span class="venue-hiring">We are hiring!</span>                                    
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: You are in fact asking, how to find specific urls from specific html document. It would help if you provide given document or it's relevent path. Anyway, you are on good track - lxml will allow you either using XPath, which will select what you need, or will allow iterating over the content and do the test case by case and extract what you need. It is very likely, one goo XPath expression will resolve your task.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky i edited my post above.  I know how to use xpath to get an href, I jsut have no idea how to use it to capture an html data- attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Searching for expected content by means of lxml

This assumes, you already have content of the page containing the data you need. The code shows fetching it by http request, if it requires rendering within browser, see later part of my answer how to get get it.

If you want to get all values in attribute `data-hiringurl`, try XPath `//@data-hiringurl`

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = "http://wearemadeinny.com/find-a-job/"

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text) # corrected, used to be `lxml.html.fromstring`

xp = "//@data-hiringurl"
job_urls = tree.xpath(xp)

print print job_urls
```

But I am not sure, if the url you have provided contain such data. I did not find it there.

## Getting content of page rendered by JavaScript

If the page gets the content you are interested in rendered dynamically on the client, you need to provide the browser context and let it render there. Using `selenium` can do the work:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> url = "http://wearemadeinny.com/find-a-job/"
>>> browser.get(url)
>>> page = browser.page_source
>>> print page
```

Now you have in `page` variable content of the page and you may proceed with `lxml` as described above.

Note: I do not guarantee, you will get the expected content in the page, I only know, it comes in rendered form. But if you need to proceed by clicking on some of the elements on the page, filling in some text, pressing buttons, all that can be done by `browser` instance shown above - just read doc.

Comment: this is returning an empty list.  the data-hiringurl attribute can be found if you use chrome dev tools and inspect element on one of the companies that says "we're hiring" on the right rail. edit: all of the companies have the data-hiringurl attribute, though some are empty.

Comment: @Barnaby If these `data-hiringurl` attributes are filled in by JavaScript, then `requests` will not bring it to `lxml`. You shall look to `mechanize` or seleninum drivers.

Comment: i assume that this is the case.  i will investigate mechanize or selenium

Comment: @Barnaby I added sample, how to use `selenium` to fetch content of your page.